How to pre-select the TeamsChannelPicker from Microsoft Graph Tools
I tried to preselect the TeamsChannelPicker with "selectedItem" :
<TeamsChannelPicker selectedItem={ item } ></TeamsChannelPicker>

Does someone knows how to pre-select it and what object or value it needs?
I couldn't find anything on the internet.
Here the official Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/teams-channel-picker?tabs=html
